What exactly is a lattice?
In the class,my teacher give me the definition of lattice as below and show me some examples.
But I was confused to the example(b): why do b and c have no least upper bound?
I think d and e is the upper bound of b and c. And intuitively, min(d,e) is the least upper bound of b and c. 

There is no ordering defined between $d$ and $e$. So you cannot do $min(d,e)$. You have no way of comparing $d$ and $e$ as per the lattice diagram.

@reinierpost No one mentioned anything that would require $c$ and $d$ in (a) to be comparable. In contrast, the OP wrote that in (b), the lub of ${b,c}$ should be “$\min(d,e)$”, and this indeed requires $d$ and $e$ to be comparable, as codeR wrote.

True, but a little terse. Thanks; I fixed my answer.

@codeR  I was trapped in the inertial thinking and thank you for your help!

By definition, the least upper bound of $\{b,c\}$ is the least element that is as least as large as every element in $\{b,c\}$.
In example 2, this element is $d$ or $e$. As you already wrote, we need to find the smaller of the two: $\min(d,e)$.
The problem is that we can't, because (as @codeR wrote), the diagram doesn't put one above the other.
